# creating coordinates from lat and long

Tags: python

I have a data frame with columns for latitude and longitude (not sure if this is a relevant detail, but just in case both are float64). I am trying to create a matrix of distances between all points, and have found that I can use  Delaunay from scipy.spatial.

But I'm not sure how to do this, I wanted to create an array called 'coord' and then use that in;

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
tri = Delaunay(coord)
```

but I'm having trouble with the array. I have tried the following

```
coord=[]

for x in df['lat']:
    for y in df['long']:
        coord.append((x,y))
```

but the kernel keeps restarting. Not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't `coord` just `df[['lat', 'long']].values.tolist()`?

Comment: As a side note, your nested loop creates a list of __all__ latitudes paired with __all__ longitudes __each__. That's why the kernel runs out of memory.

Comment: oh that's why, thanks @DYZ

Comment: @Rbcc You could also use `to_numpy` like this `df[['lat', 'long']].to_numpy().tolist()`